# Could not set unknown property 'args' for object of type org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction_Decorated

Tags: java, gradle

I have a gradle task defined as:

```
task deployController {
    mustRunAfter assemble

    doFirst {
       sometasks("${somevar}")
    }
    doLast {
        if (condition) {
            javaexec {
                classpath = someclasspath
                main = "com.somepackage.MainClass"
                workingDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}"
                args = '--add-opens=jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec=ALL-UNNAMED'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to include args to the javaexec to fix a Reflective Access error, but run into this `Could not set unknown property 'args' for object of type org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction_Decorated`. jvmArgs doesn't work either, what is the correct way to specify arguments to a javaexec task?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I used `jvmArgs += '--add-opens=jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec=ALL-UNNAMED'` instead of args